# How can I open my new account?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I accidentally made my second account with the same email as the previous village. When I log in, the old village will load instead of the new village. How can I load or open my new account?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please make sure to use correct spelling and grammar when posting so that people can respond to you easily. Thanks!

Comment: Did you bind your 2nd village to your account?

Answer (score 1):

If you have linked the second village to the same email as the first, there is no way to get it back. What you need to do is create a new village and link it to a new email.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you'll need to start over and make a new account *again*. Make a new account, either gamecenter or Google+, log into the new account, *then* make a new village. If you're on iOS, you can find a full step-by-step [here](http://clashopedia.com/guides/reset-clash-of-clans-ios-8/). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to link your game to your Google+ account (if you're on Android device)